# Cannot use style method in JS

Tags: javascript, css, html

In this code:

```
<header class="alg">Some text</header>
<script>
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("alg");
header.style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

after run it. I got from log:

`TypeError: header_m.style is undefined`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns **multiple** elements.

Therefore, you are accessing it improperly. What you want, in this case, is:

```
 header[0].style.color = 'red';
  //    ^ [0] will get the first element with the class, 
  // which is in this case your is header element. [1] would get the second, etc.
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LmG7F/)